# How do you isolate Docker contexts in large repositories?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

Say you have a repository that is mostly broken out by projects, but has some common utilities shared:

```
projectA/
  ./Dockerfile
projectB/
  ./Dockerfile
projectC/
utils/
```

Ideally you would want to build `projectA` from it's own directory, so you don't have to send the contents of `projectB` and `projectC` to the Docker context.  But what if you want to include `utils` in the context?

I know you can ignore files to send to the context via `.dockerignore`, but in this case you would keep having to change what you ignore when you build `projectA` vs. `projectB`

Comment: First things first: You **cannot** include files from outside a Dockerfile, so in your scenario, none of your Dockerfiles can access `../utils`. Do you use version control, for example git? If yes, one solution would be to have 4 git projects for your case: projectA, projectB, projectC and utils. Then, project A, B and C could include *utils* as [git submodule](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules).

Comment: You can include files from parent directories of a Dockerfile as long as the build context includes them. `docker build ../`

Comment: @Munchkin a submodule is a good idea, but I'd rather do this with Docker only.  Maintaining a submodule is work, and isn't in the spirit of a monorepo.

Comment: @Matt if I build from the parent directory, all projects are sent to the context, which is what I'm trying to avoid here.

Comment: Yep, understood. I should have @Munchkined that comment.